# Am I double tracking duplicates in pageviews?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, tracking

I have a feeling that there is a tracking issue on my website, possibly with pageviews. One of the reasons for this is that my bounce rate went from a steady 55% to a steady 8% on a precise date.

My tags are setup via GTM, although there might be a legacy analytics code somewhere.

Any idea how I can verify:

- If pageviews are triggered twice
- If I have two GA tags triggering every time
- If I have a conflict with a legacy tag and a new tag.

Website is: https://www.movingwaldo.ca

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you land on the page (tried on the homepage) you have:

- a Global site tag (gtag.js) on page that send a pageview to Google Analytics;
- Google Tag Manager that send a Universal Analytics pageview to Google Analytics;
- Google Tag Manager that send an interaction Universal Analytics event (category: *Slide-In Ad - Client*) to Google Analytics.

So you can't bounce.

**Solution**

- remove the google code from the page;
- set in Google Tag Manager the event that started automatically as `non-interaction` (because, in the specific case, it is actually an impression and not a real user iteration).

Comment: Thanks Michele! 
I just switched the Slide-In Ad... to non-interactive.

Ajout the gtag.js, wouldn't this be use to track other things than the page view? I am just worried that it if I delete it, I will lose some tracking? 

Should I remove the Universal Analytics pageview to Google Analytics in the Google Tag Manager instead?

Comment: Remove one or the other, both trace the same page view (for easier management is better to keep the one in GTM if correctly configured).